# A Fourier series solution to the Duffing equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) is

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} x(t) + \delta \frac{d}{dt} x(t) + \beta \ x(t)^3 - \alpha x = V(t)$$

My question is if anyone has tried to solve this equation by Fourier expansion of x(t), and if so, can you please point me to a paper?

TIA!

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325304962_Approximate_fully_analytical_Fourier_series_solution_to_the_forced_and_damped_Helmholtz-Duffing_oscillator

Comment: Thanks Jean Marie!

Comment: And thanks for the editing too Jean Marie.